Who is Muniswara deity worshipped in southern India?
A deity named Munishwara is worshipped in southern India. He is considered as a form or a devotee of Shiva. Not much information about him is present on the internet. Who is Lord Munishwara? Is he mentioned in Hindu scriptures with different name?

Yes, thank you.
